# How to change polymer generated image ID iron-image

Tags: polymer, web-component

I have a couple of images in my home page. I am using polymer iron-image as follow.

```
    <iron-image style="width:100%; height:150px;" background-color:="" lightgray;"="" preload="" fade="" sizing="cover" src="images/img6.jpg" alt="Jaxworks" id="img6" class="x-scope iron-image-0">

  **<div id="sizedImgDiv"** role="img" class="style-scope iron-image" aria-label="Jaxworks" style="background-image: url(&quot;images/img6.jpg&quot;); background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
        **<img id="img" class="style-scope iron-image" alt="Jaxworks" src="images/img6.jpg" hidden="">**
        **<div id="placeholder" class="faded-out style-scope iron-image" style="background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>**
      </iron-image>
```

I have about 10 of this images that are generated dynamically. The thing is each of the iron-image generated img has thesame id of **`img(id=img)(<img id="img" class="style-scope iron-image" alt="Jaxworks" src="images/img6.jpg" hidden="">)`**.

```
`<div id="sizedImgDiv"** role="img" class="style-scope iron-image" aria-label="Jaxworks" style="background-image: url(&quot;images/img6.jpg&quot;); background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>`


<div id="placeholder" class="faded-out style-scope iron-image" style="background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
```

I don't want the repeated IDS. I wonder if there is anything I can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot modify those IDs because they're used internally by `<iron-image>`. Many Polymer elements use IDs in their templates, so you'll eventually run into another instance of this.